# how to securing nodered in docker

Tags: docker, security, node-red

im trying to give a password node red flows running on docker but doesnt know how to do it

I've attempted numerous tutorials to set up password protection for my Node-RED flows, but regrettably, none of them have proven effective in guiding me through the process. It's been quite a frustrating journey, and I'm still searching for a reliable solution to secure my Node-RED flows with a robust password mechanism to enhance the overall security of my projects.

Comment: This is all explained in the [official image documention](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker). The best option IMO is the one provide there i.e. set `credentialSecret: process.env.NODE_RED_CREDENTIAL_SECRET` inside `module.exports` in your `settings.js` file and then provide the password as an envinoment variable to your container `NODE_RED_CREDENTIAL_SECRET`, either on your docker command line or in your compose file depending on how your are running your container. In this latest case, you could provide the password in a `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a copy of the `settings.js` file and edit it as described in the "Editor & Admin API security" section of the user guide.

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#editor--admin-api-security

You should then mount this file at `/data/settings.js` (It's probably best to mount a volume on `/data` to ensure your flows are persisted).

If you also enable HTTPS you will need to put the certificate & key files in the same directory.